# The trait `std::fmt::Write` is not implemented for `Stdout` when it should be

Tags: rust, io, stdout

According to the rust docs, and the browsed code inside my IDE (vscode), the `Write` trait is implemented by `std::io::Stdout` and `&Stdout` ([docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.Stdout.html#impl-Write-for-%26Stdout)).
However, when I attempt to compile my code, I get the error:

```
mode.handle_stmt(&mut out, stmt, &line_lookup))
     ----------- ^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::fmt::Write` is not implemented for `Stdout`
    |                                    |
    |                                    required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `std::fmt::Write`:
              &mut W
              Formatter<'_>
              OsString
              serde::de::format::Buf<'a>
              std::net::display_buffer::DisplayBuffer<SIZE>
              std::string::String
note: required by a bound in `Modes::handle_stmt`
```

where mode implements:

```
pub(super) trait Mode {
    fn name() -> &'static str;
    fn handle_stmt<W: std::fmt::Write>(
        w: W,
        stmt: REPLStmt<Decl, Expr, Import>,
        line_lookup: &::line_col::LineColLookup,
    ) -> Result<(), &'static str>;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what's happening here and what I can to to resolve it?

Comment: `std::fmt::Write` and `std::io::Write` are different traits. `Stdout` only implements `io::Write`.

Comment: @PitaJ Thanks, I had just noticed that myself. My fault for not reading correctly

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, I wasn't reading correctly:
`std::io::Stdout` implements `std::io::Write`, I was expecting `std::fmt::Write` which is not just a re-export.

Resolved by changing my trait to use `io::Write` and using a `Vec<u8>` instead of a `String` in the other instance of the method being called.

Comment: Yep, the reuse of the name for both traits is considered a mistake, but now is too late to fix...