# Why does the Rust standard library implement traits for both Thing and &Thing?

Tags: rust

I was reading the question [The trait `std::fmt::Write` is not implemented for `Stdout` when it should be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74706799/the-trait-stdfmtwrite-is-not-implemented-for-stdout-when-it-should-be) where the asker noted that the rust documentation shows that the std::io::Write trait is implemented for both [&Stdout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.Stdout.html#impl-Write-for-%26Stdout) and [Stdout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.Stdout.html#impl-Write-for-Stdout).

I don't understand why this is necessary or how you would use it. Isn't everything you define for `Thing` always implemented for `&Thing`? Why would you implement something for `&Thing` without implementing it for it's definition?

Comment: `drop` is implemented for all `T` but it obviously doesn't drop `x` when passed `&x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't everything you define for `Thing` always implemented for `&Thing`?

No, an implementation for a type `T` will *not* automatically implement anything for `&T`. Now, sometimes blanket implementations can kick in, and if you pass a `&&T` to a function expecting a `&T`, then Rust will insert dereferences for you, but that does not mean the trait was implemented for `&T`, just that Rust helped you out a bit.

> Why would you implement something for `&Thing` without implementing it for it's definition?

There's a very good example of that which we use all the time: [`String::from`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html#impl-From%3C%26str%3E-for-String).

```
impl From<&str> for String {
  fn from(value: &str) -> String {
    ...
  }
}
```

`From::<T>::from` takes an argument, by value. No references or anything, just straight-up a value of type `T`. So we can never write a `From<str>` implementation for *anything*, since `str` is unsized and hence cannot be a function argument on its own. But it makes perfect sense to convert a `&str` to a `String`: that's just making an owned copy of the string.

Comment: I think it is good to note that while autoref may allow methods to be called on references, the trait is still not implemented for them and it affects generics and dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Ah, this actually helps me quite a bit. Coming from higher level languages I was viewing `&Thing` as a different type of `Thing`. Really, it is more like an instance of type `ThingReference`.

Comment: @etchesketch Yep, that's a very good way of thinking about it. `&Thing` could (theoretically) have been implemented as a type `ReferenceTo<Thing>` which takes one generic argument. It's a different type that happens to *depend on* `Thing`. There are things that make working with references easier (autoref, the trait `Deref`, covering rules for references, etc.) that are baked into the compiler, but at it's core it's a distinct type.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Silvio-Mayolo's answer: in this particular case, there was originally just an implementation for `Stdout`; and [the more-flexible implementation for `&Stdout` was added later](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/76275), which provides a strict superset of functionality, notably allowing you to share the reference between threads. The original implementation can't be removed without breaking backwards compatibility with existing code using the by-value implementation (auto-deref isn't perfect, you would still need to go back and add an `&` in some situations).